# Formatting numbers in a specific column of a file inplace

Tags: shell, awk, formatting

I'm trying to format the `Amount` col to 2 decimal format like `1000` to `1000.00`

I have a sample file like below

```
Bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
xyz|we||100||
xyz|we||100.1||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
xyz|errt||-230.0||
xyz|ss||234.78||
xyz|we|valid|990.2||
xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922.9||
xyz|we||.9||
xyz|we||.0||
xyz|we||.00||
```

I tried `awk -F"|" '{OFS=FS}''{printf ("%.2f",$4) ; print }' test.csv` which resulted in

```
0.00Bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
100.00xyz|we||100||
100.10xyz|we||100.1||
23459900.00xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
-230.00xyz|errt||-230.0||
234.78xyz|ss||234.78||
990.20xyz|we|valid|990.2||
9922.90xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922.9||
0.90xyz|we||.9||
0.00xyz|we||.0||
0.00xyz|we||.00||
0.00
```

Also I want to avoid the header line and replace in the original file.Please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Replace `"%.2f"` with `"%.2f\n"` to see the problem.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question across multiple sites (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607994/formatting-numbers-in-a-specific-column-of-a-file-inplace)

Comment: ok Noted Sundeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit your file "inplace" with GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR>1{$4=sprintf("%.2f",$4); print}' file
```

Output:

```
xyz|we||100.00||
xyz|we||100.10||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
xyz|errt||-230.00||
xyz|ss||234.78||
xyz|we|valid|990.20||
xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922.90||
xyz|we||0.90||
xyz|we||0.00||
xyz|we||0.00||
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: I think you meant to put the `print` inside `NR>1` block? And `-i inplace` option since you mention `GNU awk`

Comment: @Sundeep: `print` is intentionally placed outside so that the header line is also printed.

Comment: OP doesn't want the header though `Also I want to avoid the header line and replace in the original file.` ... on second thoughts, perhaps OP meant that header line shouldn't be affected by the code?

Comment: yes, header line is not to be affected, thats what I meant, sorry for ambiguous wordings. Perfect answer.

Comment: @Naveen "not to be affected" is different from "not to be printed". Do you want the header line printed or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can just detect if the field is a number with the test `$4+0==$4` and replace the field if so:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     $4+0==$4 {$4=sprintf("%.2f", $4)} 1' file
```

Prints:

```
Bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
xyz|we||100.00||
xyz|we||100.10||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
xyz|errt||-230.00||
xyz|ss||234.78||
xyz|we|valid|990.20||
xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922.90||
xyz|we||0.90||
xyz|we||0.00||
xyz|we||0.00||
```

If you want to skip the header line, just add `NR==1 {next}`